# To use and test twilio in different environments do I need to use different numbers and apps?

Tags: sms, twilio

Here's the scenario:
In production, I want to send and receive sms messages.
In qa, I want to whitelist the numbers that can be sent to, plus receive sms at a qa-specific url.
In test, I want to whitelist the numbers that can be sent to, plus receive sms at a test-specific url.

As far as I can tell, the only/best way to do this in twilio is to set up three distinct phone numbers and three distinct TwiML apps to get the urls all pointing at the right place for the incoming messages.

Am I missing anything?  Is there an alternative way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio must send all inbound SMS to a phone number to the same URL, so if you only had one number, you could only use one endpoint for inbound SMS. However, at that endpoint you could have specific handling logic for messages based on the number that is sending an inbound SMS. So if you are sending all of your test messages from +12345, at your URL endpoint you could check for a From address matching +12345 and handle that specially, otherwise use your regular production logic.

Otherwise yes, I believe you'd have to register separate numbers to do what you want :(